# Javascript Map multiple values into list

Tags: javascript

I currently have an array ... code goes like this:

```
namelist=[];

var namelist = mydata.cars.map( o => o.name );
```

This gives me the name of the cars.

What I want to do it to pass several values instead of just one so I get then call for them when needed.

For example id and name.

How can I do this?

Comment: Can you add sample input and sample output for what you want? It is not clear at the moment.

Comment: Just use `mydata.cars`, then.

Answer (score 74):

Using the ES6 style you may have have a problem doing:

```
.map(o => {name: o.name, id: o.id})
```

Because the curly braces mean that you start a block, not an object.
If that is the problem you are having, you should use that block, with a return statement:

```
.map(o => { return {name: o.name, id: o.id} })
```

Or, create an object by using the constructor:

```
.map(o => new Object({name: o.name, id: o.id}))
```

**UPDATE:**

You can also do:

```
.map(o => ({name: o.name, id: o.id}))
```

Comment: Is there a way to return multiple objects?

Comment: If you want to return multiple objects, you can use the `flatMap` function.